# (iOS Cordova) Accessing local files from remote - WKWebview

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

Having the following variables:

- remote web presented in cordova
- local files that the remote web asks for with the following code:

```
    var url = "https://cdvfile/localhost/" + localFolder + "/www/cordova.js";
    var element = document.createElement('script');
    element.id = "cordova";
    element.type = "text/javascript";
    element.onerror = function () {
        //error
    }
    element.onload = function () {
        //success - code to be executed upon success
    }
    element.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
```

This fails in WKWebView with the obvious error

> [Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname
> could not be found. (cordova.js, line 0)

As you know, WKUrlSchemeHandler doesn't intercept http/https requests. An alternative is to use the dangerous `[NSURLProtocol wk_registerScheme:@"https"];` private API trick (and it works but then it somehow screws up the request to load the page that includes the code above (doesn't add some cookies and some weird behavior).

I do have another alternative to inject via `[userContentController addUserScript:script]` but this requires modifying the remote web part in order to execute the code that follows the success of the script injection request.

I know it was previously possible to do all this with cdvfile:// in UIWebView but I am looking for a way to do all this WITHOUT modifying the remote (meaning, the url has to stay as you see it above. I've racked my brains for a few months now with this but can't come up with a solution. Please don't ask why I'm doing this or say that this is stupid etc, I have no choice, it's what I gotta do and it doesn't depend on me.

Please send help, thoughts, prayers etc

Thanks